# Rotas dos controllers e actions em minúsculo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-4

Como fazer com que as rotas dos *controllers* e *actions* sejam todas em minúsculo?

Por exemplo: ao invés de `Noticias/Details` ficar `noticias/details`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É possível usar uma [biblioteca](https://lowercaseroutesmvc.codeplex.com/) ([Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LowercaseRoutesMVC)) para fazer isto. Lá tem as indicações de como instalar e usá-la. È possível que o projeto tenha sido abandonado. [Alternativa](https://www.programmersought.com/article/39172128299/).

Mas se estiver usando o .NET 4.5 ou maior tem como configurar sem bibliotecas:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/RoutesInLower.cs).

Retirado da [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11647303/221800). Na mesma pergunta tem outras formas de fazer isto.

Comment: Essa biblioteca é show. Valeu mano!